# javascript confirmation box issue

Tags: javascript

I used confirm box on this link

```
<a href="<?php echo Yii::$app->params["url"]; ?>admin/index/deletcompany&companyid=<?php echo $Companydata['company_id']; ?>&userid=<?php echo $userid; ?>" id="<?php echo $Companydata['company_id']; ?>" onclick="confirmdialog()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" title="Delete"></span></a>
```

Javascript code

```
function confirmdialog(e){
     var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this company?");
        if(r == true)
        {

         return true;
        }
        else
        {
         return false;
      }     

    }
```

But every case action perform then click on cancel .Please give me my question.

Comment: try to change onclick="confirmdialog()" to onclick="return confirmdialog();"

Comment: this will add a return false. means anchor tag do nothing on click bcz you are already return nothing(false);

Comment: There is no jQuery here - so ive made your tag more appropriate

Answer (score 2):

Without using Onclick event and custom function:

```
<a href="javascript:if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this company?')){ window.location='<?php echo Yii::$app->params["url"]; ?>admin/index/deletcompany&companyid=<?php echo $Companydata['company_id']; ?>&userid=<?php echo $userid; ?>'; };" id="<?php echo $Companydata['company_id']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" title="Delete"></span></a>
```

By using custom function for Onclick event:

```
<a href="<?php echo Yii::$app->params["url"]; ?>admin/index/deletcompany&companyid=<?php echo $Companydata['company_id']; ?>&userid=<?php echo $userid; ?>" id="<?php echo $Companydata['company_id']; ?>" onclick="return confirmdialog();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" title="Delete"></span></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmdialog(){
        return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this company?');
    }
</script>
```

By using JQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="my_anchors" href="<?php echo Yii::$app->params["url"]; ?>admin/index/deletcompany&companyid=<?php echo $Companydata['company_id']; ?>&userid=<?php echo $userid; ?>" id="<?php echo $Companydata['company_id']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" title="Delete"></span></a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( ".my_anchors" ).click(function() {
          return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this company?');
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this html `onclick="return confirmdialog()"`

```
<a href="delete.php" onclick="return confirmdialog()">delete</a>
```

and js

```
function confirmdialog(e){
 if(!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this company?"){
     return false;
  }     

}
```